# Composite unique Index

Tags: c#, entity-framework, composite-key, ef-fluent-api

i have the following models, i want to specify using FluentApi that the paire in table A, B.Id and C.Id are unique

```
class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }
}
class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If combination of B and C is unique, do you really need Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with just navigation properties.

You need to add the explicit FK fields:

```
class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int B_Id { get; set; }
    public int C_Id { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }
}
```

and create an unique index using the following Fluent API configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasRequired(e => e.B).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.B_Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasRequired(e => e.C).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.C_Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<A>().Property(e => e.B_Id).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", 
    new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_BC", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
modelBuilder.Entity<A>().Property(e => e.C_Id).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", 
    new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_BC", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
```